# MUI leftsidebar is not closing when clicking on Backdrop

Tags: material-ui

We have an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqw48u?file=/demo.tsx) for drawer from material-ui.
But this drawer doesn't have backdrop when we open the left sidebar.  So I changed their code to get backdrop.
On *line 113*, we have `variant="persistent"` so I changed this to `variant="temporary"` to get backdrop effect.
But if we click on backdrop, left-sidebar is not closing. (You can test it here with my example : https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-framework-7wgiqs?file=/demo.tsx, just click on menu icon, and you will see left-sidebar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onClose={(_, reason) => reason === "backdropClick" && setOpen(false)}` in the `Drawer` component for MUI v5.

```
<Drawer
    sx={{
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
        width: drawerWidth,
        boxSizing: "border-box"
      }
    }}
    variant="temporary"
    anchor="left"
    open={open}
    onClose={(_, reason) => reason === "backdropClick" && setOpen(false)}
  >
```

Here is the working [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ride-dm23gn?file=/demo.tsx:3359-3674) based on your code.

Comment: Dear, you have attached `onClick` on `Drawer` itself. So if we click on any part of left-sidebar, it will gonna close. But I want to close the drawer only when we click on backdrop.

Comment: Ok I understand better now @Abhishekkamal , I have updated my code and the sandbox, let me know if it helps.